# SMTP localhost unable to send emails to local domain but send to external domains works?

Tags: windows, iis-7, smtp, iis-6

We have set up an SMTP server using IIS Manager 6. The website is managed through IIS7. It will send emails to any external email address, but emails to our own domain never leave the queue! We verified that we are able to perform an NSLookup of our own domain from that box, and we can.

Has anyone ever seen this problem before? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone's knowledge: It ended up being a messed-up MX record someone set up a long time ago.